# How to find paths matches a sub-string in a root directory recursively?

Tags: shell, find, substring

I want to find file paths that matches a specific sub-string in a specific root directory.

Below is my shell script. When I test one by one, the results are good. But when I loop, the result is empty. Who can give advice on the cause?

**my script**

```
filename=include_pattern
cat $filename | while read LINE
do
    echo $LINE
    path=$(echo $LINE |cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1)
    echo $path
    result=$(find . -path $path)
    echo $result
done
```

**include_pattern**

```
file('.*/cm-audio/src/main/*')
file('.*/cm-common/include/cm_common/utils/*')
```

I extract only the contents of file () by

```
path=$(echo $LINE |cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1)
```

Now, I try to find paths including sub-string $path by

```
find . -path $path
```

The result is empty.

However, if I try it by standalone in command line, it returns path lists. for example,

```
find . -path '.*/cm-audio/src/main*'
```

I cannot the reason why this full script doesn't work.
Could you let me some advice about this?

Comment: remove the `'` in the pattern file, e.g. from `file('.*/cm-audio/src/main/*')` make `file(.*/cm-audio/src/main/*)` - or - `find . -path "${path//'}"`

Comment: See edit part of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
filename='text_file_containing_include_pattern_on_each_line.txt'
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    path=$(echo "$line" |cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1)
    find \. -path "${path//\'}"
done < $filename
```

Ah wait.. I thought you where reading from a textfile that contained lines like:

```
file('.*/cm-audio/src/main/*')
file('.*/cm-common/include/cm_common/utils/*')
```

But I see now I was mistaken.. let me adapt my answer in a sec..

**EDIT**

In case you stored your include_pattern in a variable:

```
include_pattern="file('.*/cm-audio/src/main/*')
file('.*/cm-common/include/cm_common/utils/*')"
for file in $include_pattern; do
    path=$(echo "$file" |cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1)
    find \. -path "${path//\'}"
done
```

Comment: I have one more question. If some of paths ends with /.*' not /*', how can I handle this exception case? For example, '.*/power-manager/PowerManager/.*'

Comment: Both paths should be processed correctly if they are entered into the `include_pattern`. Also, all paths that end with `/.*` should also be found via `/*` since the asterix will iterate over any available character.. so it will also iterate over `.`. If you restrict your path to `/.*` be aware that you will only find hidden files or folders since those are the only ones starting with a `.`.